# Python recursive function with print reverse digits

Tags: python, recursion

Recently, I am practicing writing code for "recursive functions". this, I am trying to code one function called reverse digits and I notice that there are lots of different ways to do that. My code works in IDLE when I use return. For example:

```
def reverse_digits(num):
if num < 10:
    return num
else:
    return str(num%10) + str(reverse_digits(num//10))
print(reverse_digits(1234))
```

However, I want to print the result in the recursive function, for example,

```
def reverse_digits(num):
if num < 10:
    return num
else:
    print(str(num%10) + str(reverse_digits(num//10)))
reverse_digits(1234)
```

I would get

```
21
3None
4None
```

Anyone can explain why?

Or help me to improve the code?

Comment: Yes, when you *print* something that does *not* mean hat the function returns that something, so if you want to show the steps, you need to *both* `print` and `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not explicitly `return` something, the function in Python will return `None`. In your second implementation, you `print` the result of a certain expression, but in that codepath, you do *not* return it.

You can fix this with:

```
def reverse_digits(num):
    if num < 10:
        return num
    else:
        res = str(num%10) + str(reverse_digits(num//10))
        print(res)
        return res

print(reverse_digits(1234))
```

So we calculate it, and return it.

Note that it is however more efficient to stay in the `int` domain, instead of doing all sorts of string processing, and thus implement it like:

```
def reverse_digits(num, rem = 0):
    if not num:
        return rem
    else:
        return reverse_digits(num // 10, 10 * rem + (num % 10))
```

Given all arithmetic can be done in constant time, this will result in an *O(n)* algorithm, whereas the former will typically take *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have another concern which is it would print three times from 21, 321 until 4321, how can we get 4321 just one time but using a recursive function. I try to delete something but it wouldn't work.

Comment: @neilissac: remove the `print(..)` in the outer call (last line), since this will obtain the result, and reprint it.